# Matrix transformation displaying values

Tags: html, css, matrix, transformation

I need to give the matrix in code values, but I don`t have any idea how to do that.
 Can You help me ?

That's how many values i should get

[image: That's how many values i should get]

```
<html lang="pl">
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>New</title>
<style type="text/css">
body font-size:20px; margin:0px 100px;
div position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px; width:100px; height:100px;
background-color:rgba(180,220,180,0.2);border: 1px dotted red;
#el1 transform: rotate(122deg) scale(0.7080,1.0700) translate(15px,34px);
#el2 transform: matrix(//here);
</style></head>
<body><h1>Transformation</h1>
<div id="el1">el 1</div>
<div id="el2">el 2</div>
</body></html>
</pre>
```

Sorry for bad editing.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

CSS matrix use 6 values:

`matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)`

Example:

```
.active{
  transform: matrix(1, 2, -1, 1, 80, 80);
}
```